# Error populating DataTable with OdbcDataAdapter using LEFT() within c# MySQL Statement

Tags: c#, mysql, datatable, odbc

I have a problem with my DataTable accepting the contents of an OdbcDataAdapter.

```
public static DataTable queryTable(string pStatement, OdbcConnection pConnection)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter(pStatement, pConnection);
    da.Fill(dt);

    return dt;
}
```

When the code hits the da.Fill(dt); an exception is thrown:

> OdbcException was unhandled by user code. ERROR [42S22] Column not found.

This SQL statement works fine:

```
"SELECT TOP 10 DETAILS AS 'JobReference' FROM AUDIT_SPLIT"
```

But when I change the statement to this:

```
"SELECT TOP 10 Left([DETAILS],9) AS 'JobReference' FROM AUDIT_SPLIT"
```

I get the error. I have tried variations on using parenthesis and quotation marks.

The SQL Statement is a valid statement in MSAccess and MySQL.

Can anyone explain a way of using LEFT() or MID() or SUBSTRING() with the OdbcDataAdapter and DataTable.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there:

```
public static DataTable queryTable(string pStatement, OdbcConnection pConnection)
{
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter(pStatement, pConnection);
    var DS = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(DS);
    dt = DS.Tables[0];

    return dt;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately 'var' type is not an option for me as the code is using .net 2.0, any other suggestion?